# Merging select variables from two Ansible lists when they have a matching variable

Tags: ansible

I can't seem to figure this out in Ansible, but could do it in Python pretty easy. 
 I have two different lists that get returned to me from a module.  The module (ntc-ansible) is essentially connecting to a network switch and getting port info using two different show commands.  Basically I want to iterate over list #1 and list #2 and if the port # matches, merge the variables from each list into a new list.  For example I might get this(and more data) back from the module:

```
list1 = [
    {
        "description": "Switch #1", 
        "port": "Gi1/1", 
        "protocol": "up", 
        "status": "up"
    }, 
    {
        "description": "Switch #2", 
        "port": "Gi1/5", 
        "protocol": "up", 
        "status": "up"
    }
] 

list2 = [                    {
    {
        "duplex": "a-full", 
        "name": "Switch #1", 
        "port": "Gi1/1", 
        "speed": "a-1000", 
        "status": "connected", 
        "type": "10/100/1000BaseT", 
        "vlan": "trunk"
    }, 
    {
        "duplex": "a-full", 
        "name": "Some Server", 
        "port": "Gi1/2", 
        "speed": "a-100", 
        "status": "connected", 
        "type": "10/100/1000BaseT", 
        "vlan": "trunk"
    }
]
```

I want to loop over list1 then loop over list2.  If the port matches, merge the dict entries into a new list so that I get the correct variables for the port in question.  To make it worse, I dont want to merge all vars, only select ones.

Hopefully I'm making sense...  If I was doing this in Python, I might do:

```
new_list = []
for port_a in list1:
    temp_dict = {}
    for port_b in list2:
        if port_a['port'] == port_b['port']:
            temp_dict['port'] = port_a['port']
            temp_dict['desc'] = port_a['description']
            temp_dict['status'] = port_b['status']
            temp_dict['vlan'] = port_b['vlan']
            temp_dict['speed'] = port_b['speed']
            temp_dict['duplex'] = port_b['duplex']
            temp_dict['type'] = port_b['type']
            new_list.append(temp_dict)
```

In the above lists, I would only get port "Gi1/1" in the new list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `with_together`.

```
- set_fact:
    new_list: "{{ new_list|default([]) + [' {{item.0}}|union({{item.1}}) '] }}"
  when: item.0.port == item.1.port
  with_together:
    - "{{list1}}"
    - "{{list2}}"
```